# Is it correct: natural-logarithm maps algebraic numbers to transcendentals and vice-verse, over the domain it is defined?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

Is it correct that the natural logarithm function maps algebraic numbers to transcendental and transcendental numbers to algebraic, other than 1? Of course, over the domain natural log is defined i.e. $(0,\infty)$?

i.e.

$$\ln:A^+ \rightarrow T \hspace{5 mm};\hspace{5 mm} \ln:T^+ \rightarrow A,$$

and$$\ln:A^+ \nrightarrow A \hspace{5 mm};\hspace{5 mm} \ln:T^+ \nrightarrow T.$$

where;

$A^+$ is the set of positive algebraic numbers except $1$.

$T^+$ is the set of positive transcendental numbers.

$T$ is the set of transcendental numbers.

$A$ is the set of algebraic numbers.

Comment: Are you familiar with the cardinalities of these sets?

Comment: A is countable and T is not.

Comment: Yes.  And you are aware that $\ln$ is injective on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, ln is injective.

Comment: Then, it is possible that $ln(t_1)=t_2$; where $t_1,t_2 \in \{Transcendental\}$. And my assertion in question is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is impossible for cardinality reasons alone, since $\ln$ is injective, so it cannot map an uncountable set into a countable one.

It is true that $\ln$ maps positive algebraic numbers (except 1) to transcendental numbers, by [the Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).  Every algebraic real number except $0$ is the logarithm of a positive transcendental number, but so are most transcendental numbers.  For a concrete example, [$e^\pi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant) is a transcendental number whose logarithm is transcendental.

Comment: Well, if I say instead: $Ln:A^+ \rightarrow T$ and $Ln:A^+ \nrightarrow T$, would always hold true?

Comment: If $A^+$ is the set of positive algebraic real numbers except $1$, then the logarithm restricted to $A^+$ maps into $T$: $\ln(A^+)\subseteq T$.

Comment: thanks, for detailed clarification.

Comment: You're welcome.  As a side note, some of your notation isn't standard.  E.g. "$\in$" is used to show containment of an element in a set, not set equality.  I edited to adjust the definitions at the end of your answer.

Comment: I thought $e^\pi$ being transcendental was an open problem. When was that solved?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: $e^\pi$ is a hyperlink in my answer.  (Same link as in kaka's comment).

Comment: Ah, so it is. It does not render in a visible way in the SE android app.